# Typecasting to Generic class in Swift

Tags: ios, swift, generics, swift-protocols

Im trying to typecast an object to a class that uses Generics. Here is some code for better understanding

I've a protocol named `wheel`

```
protocol Wheel
```

I've a class named `Wings`

```
class Wings {
   var count = 2
}
```

Now, I have a generic class named `VehicleWrapper`

```
class VehicleWrapper<T: Wings&Wheel> {
   var vehicle: T
}
```

Now finally I have an object which I would want to typecast to `VehicleWrapper` and use the `count` property from `Wings` class but I dont know the type `T` would be while typecasting this. Is there a way to typecast this and use the `count` variable?

Comment: The problem is that a vehicle contains `name` which is of some type conforming to `Car` and `Wheel`. That looks like a bit crazy because you would access wings using `vehicle.name.wings`.

Comment: It seems like there might be a misunderstanding here -- it seems unlikely that you would want the `name` to be a `Car` and `Wheel`. I think you want the *Vehicle* to be a `Car` and `Wheel` (`class Vehicle : Car, Wheel`). It's unclear what type `name` would be. It's also a little unclear what you mean that you "have an object which I would want to typecast to Vehicle" -- what type is it now?

Comment: It doesn't look like generics are really what you want here. How is a vehicle specialised by `Car` or `Wheel`?  Remember that different genericised types of `Vehicle` aren't co-variant.  So, for example, if you had `Vehicle<Car>` and `Vehicle<Truck>` there is no easy way to operate on instances of those two types.  Don't try and use generics when inheritance or protocol adoption will meet your needs.

Comment: Sorry for bad naming of Class/Protocols. I have updated it a bit now.

Comment: `have an object which I would want to typecast to Vehicle`

The object is something that conforms to both Wings and Wheel but we dont exactly know what it is when we are typecasting.

Comment: Can you include some example code that represents that scenario? It seems strange that you'd be "typecasting" into a `class` like this. It seems like you'd already know if it was a `VehicleWrapper` or not...

Comment: I still suspect you are misusing generics.  You don't need to know the concrete type of `vehicle` - You know it conforms to `Wings` and therefore it has a `count` property - You can just access `vehicleWrapperInstance.vehicle.count`

Comment: Seems like a valid question. Stop hating iOS devs!

Answer (score 2):

One problem with your question is that your code is illegal. You can't just say `protocol Wheel` like that; you need curly braces (which may or may not contains the protocol's requirements). And your VehicleWrapper has no initializer, so the compiler will never allow it.

But let's suppose we've taken care of all that. My guess, then, is that the problem you're having is that it is not permitted to cast to a generic. For example, you cannot cast to a VehicleWrapper. This is because a generic is not a type. The type is the *resolved* generic.

To illustrate:

```
protocol Wheel {}
class Wings {
    var count = 2
}
class VehicleWrapper<T: Wings & Wheel> {
    var vehicle: T
    init(vehicle: T) { self.vehicle = vehicle }
}

class Thing: Wings, Wheel {}

let thing = Thing()

class What<T: Wings & Wheel>: VehicleWrapper<T> {}

let what = What(vehicle: thing)

if let what = what as? VehicleWrapper { // compile error
    print(what.vehicle.count)
}
```

As you can see, our attempt cast to a VehicleWrapper is met with scorn from the compiler. We could legally, however, try casting to a `VehicleWrapper<Thing>`.

The real issue for your question is that it is difficult to imagine a use case where it make sense to need to do that, since how could this object come into existence in the first place without your knowing what it is?

Answer (score 0):

It isn't clear what you are trying to achieve, but I don't think that generics are the way to achieve it.

Generics essentially allow you to define operations on types, independent of what those types are.  This is different to inheritance or protocols that allow you define the operations that can be performed on a particular type.

Most importantly, different generic object types are not co-variant; There is no functional relationship between `GenericClass<SuperClass>` and `GenericClass<SubclassOfSuperClass>` even though the generic types do have a inheritance relationship.

Taking your example, you are probably better off using some protocols.

Consider

```
protocol Wheeled {
    var numberOfWheels: Int { get }
}

protocol Movable {
    func moveForward()
    func stop()
}
```

Now, we can define a `Vehicle` class and some subclasses in terms of those protocols:

```
class Vehicle: Movable {
    var name: String 
    var seatingCapacity: Int
    
    init(name: String, seatingCapacity: Int) {
        self.name = name
        self.seatingCapacity = seatingCapacity
    }
    func moveForward() {}
    func stop() {}
}

class Car: Vehicle, Wheeled {
    var numberOfWheels: Int
    init(name: String) {
        self.numberOfWheels = 4
        super.init(name: name, seatingCapacity: 5)
    }
}
class Truck: Vehicle, Wheeled {
    var numberOfWheels: Int
    init(name: String) {
        self.numberOfWheels = 18
        super.init(name: name, seatingCapacity: 2)
    }
}
```

Now, let's define a light aircraft:

```
protocol Winged {
    var numberOfWings: Int { get } 
    func takeOff()
    func land()
}

class LightAirplane: Vehicle, Wheeled, Winged {
    var numberOfWheels: Int
    var numberOfWings: Int
    init(name: String) {
        self.numberOfWheels = 3
        self.numberOfWings = 2
        super.init(name: name, seatingCapacity: 4)
    }
    func takeOff() {}
    func land() {}
}
```

Using these definitions we can take an `Vehicle` (whether it is a car, truck or plane) and ask it to `moveForward()` or `stop()`.

We can take an object that conforms to `Winged` and ask it to `takeOff()` and `land()`.

Where could you use generics?  Let's look at our `Truck` - We can make that a generic class:

```
class CargoTruck<Cargo>: Truck {
    private (set) var cargo: Cargo?

    init(name: String, cargo: Cargo? = nil) {
        self.cargo = cargo
        super.init(name: name)
    }

    func load(cargo: Cargo) {
        self.cargo = cargo
    }
    func unload() {
        self.cargo = nil
    }
}
```

Now we have a subclass of `Truck` that can load and unload some sort of `Cargo` but our implementation doesn't need to care what it is:

```
struct Cattle {}
struct Appliance {}

var cattleTruck = CargoTruck(name:"Cattle Truck", cargo:[Cattle]())
var applianceTruck = CargoTruck(name:"Container Truck", cargo: Appliance()))
```

We have `cattleTruck` which is a `CargoTruck<[Cattle]?` - i.e. it can hold an array of `Cattle` and `applianceTruck` which is a `CargoTruck<Appliance>` - It can hold a single `Appliance`

What if we wanted to limit the type of the cargo - We can add a constraint to the generic type:

```
protocol ShippingContainer {
}

struct StandardContainer: ShippingContainer {
}

struct RefrigeratedContainer: ShippingContainer {
}

class ContainerTruck<Cargo: ShippingContainer>: CargoTruck<Cargo> {
}

let refer = ContainerTruck(name: "ReferTruck", cargo: RefrigeratedContainer())
refer.unload()

let bad = ContainerTruck(name:"Error", cargo: 12) // Error an Int is not a container
```

The generic doesn't define what the truck can do (move, load, unload etc), but rather what it does it *to* - It can `load` a `ShippingContainer`